# How to make sure the website is internationalization compliant?

Tags: manual-testing, internationalization

We have a requirement to make sure one of our application is internationalization compliant. How to check this? What are all the items need to be verified?
Is there any tool available to verify this? Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

i18n support means making application output relevant to local standards of data representation, so 1st of all you need to **establish the requirement on what exactly you'd like to have compliant and for which locales**. This might include (but not limited to):

- Using local language
- Using local date/time format
- Using local number representation format
- Using local currency (symbols, size of fraction part, etc)
- Providing localized audio/video content
- Processing content or assuring user-to server communication compliant to local laws and regulations
- Some UX specific that is relevant to particular locales

So **i18n does not just mean translate the text**. This makes impossible to have dedicated software to test localization. The main challenge is to build test environment that would make your app get into required locale state. This might depend on different things, depending on lot of factors some of which are easy to work around (like cookies or request headers) and some are hard to work around such as end user IP address.

Answer (score 0):

International testing is the best approach being used by Software testing comapnies to make sure websites are internationalization-compliant.

International testing commonly known as i18n testing is the process of verifying the application under test to work uniformly across multiple regions and cultures.

The main purpose of internationalization is to check if the code can handle all international support without breaking functionality.

**How to perform International testing**
Various areas are impacted when an application is internationalized. In order to ensure the application is working as expected, we need to concentrate our testing on following important aspects:

1) Language

Unicode text to cater to character encoding
Number systems
Writing directions
Spelling variants
Capitalization and sorting rules
Keyboard shortcuts and layouts

2) Culture and region

Names and titles
Government numbers (Social Security number is the USA) and passports
Colors and images
Telephone numbers, zip codes, Address formats
Paper Sizes
Weights and measures
Currency symbol and currency market position
3) Dates and Important Events

Date and time formats
Calendar types (Gregorian, Lunar etc.)
Number formats (decimal separators, grouping of digits etc.)

Testing coverage: i18n testing for application should cover testing of all below modules:

1) Content localization

2) Feature-based

3) Locale/ Culture awareness

4) User Interface

5) Rendering

6) File transfer

7) Database